# I want to present a completed wordpress page to another person

Tags: database, wordpress, move

I want to present a completed wordpress page to another person but currently my site only works locally. I'm working with xampp on how I can put it on a test server so that another party can view it on their own machine. I want a free storage space and I don't even know the database to save it. Can you offer any help or a link or some program?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool called ngrok which provides a secure tunneling. You will get a temporary url for your localhost. More information is at: https://ngrok.com

Comment: I found a video for it and did it accordingly, but even with this it is only localon, how can I implement it with this so that I can send a link where it can be viewed from another computer? @Ujjawal Poonia

Comment: This software is made to to do exactly what you want, you just have to configure it properly, i have used it in past.